Ansible Detached Mode Task For Windows
I would like to understand  how to how can I create a fire-and-forget mechanism for a python scripts in my playbook. Specifically I want the task to start my basic python web server. The problem is that the script start a listening loop so the task is stuck forever.
I viewed previous similar question for Linux machine and tried to convert it to the windows version like so:
- name: Run
  win_shell: |
  Start-Process -FilePath "python" -ArgumentList "WebServer.py"
  args:
  chdir: C:\\cbg\\blind_eagle\\web
  register: webserver_resultWebServer.py


However this method does not actually load the server as expected.
It is worth noting that running the script manually does work properly.
What could be the reason for this?
